# Convert long to a CString in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, type-conversion, long-integer, cstring

I am working with **C++** with **Visual studio 2008** IDE. I need to convert long to a CString (or some other format that will work well with CString). Once I have it converted, I need to concatenate it to another CString. Something like this (but open to suggestions):

```
CString = CString + convertToCString(long)
```

**Question 1:** What is the **best way** (and please explain why an approach is superior over others) for the conversion?

For now, I am using **_ltow_s**:

```
CString = CString + _ltow_s (long)
```

_ltow_s is returning WCHAR. So I end up with:

```
CString = CString + WCHAR
```

**Question 2:** Is that concatenation safe and will yield the desired result? Is the concatenation of ‘*CString + WCHAR*’ results with a valid CString?

**Question 3:** If we are going down the rout of using _ltow_s, what is the buffer size that needed to be allocated? 32? also, is there a define for base 10 (decimal)?

**Update:**
I found this thread: [How to cast a LONG to a CString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531556/how-to-cast-a-long-to-a-cstring)
I like it as it gives many options. What is still missing is what is the preferred way for different scenarios (within reason). Robustness, safety etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CString cstr;
cstr.Format("%ld", long);
```

Comment: Thanks. What is 'cs'? Where it's coming from?

Comment: It think that it should be  cstr.Format("%ld",long);

Comment: @robert, I updated the question 1 for more clarity (please explain why an approach is superior over others).

Comment: You want a CString result. So using the CString::Format function is superior for (1) clarity/readability, and (2) you don't have to create a buffer as you do for _ltow_s.

Comment: This is not a complete answer but it is the only one to date. I will accept it...